# QtCreator сборка CMake - как добавить библиотеку?

Tags: qtcreator, cmake

Хочу настроить сборку в QtCreator через CMake.
Как добавить библиотеку в проект? например winsock2

CMakeLists:

```
project(untitled26)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Answer (score 1):

Для подключения библиотек используется макрос `target_link_libraries`, параметрами которого является целевой проект и список подключаемых библиотек.
Библиотеки указываются без стандартного префикса 'lib'.
Пример подключения libSDL2 SDL2-image

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2 SDL2_image)
```

Подробнее можно почитать, например, на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/155467/)